# Manage recurring events android

Tags: android, scheduling, android-calendar

I'm building an android app which is supposed to manage events scheduled by user and I'm a bit confused about its architecture. 
**Basic requirements:**

- User is able to  configure recurring rule for the event. App is able to notify user when the event has occurred.
- User is able to change rule configuration.
- App need to keep track of states of individual event instances(status: accepted, dismissed)
  So I got 2 questions:
- **Which is the best way to manage/store  events into db?** 
  Currently I intend to use  [table like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178644.aspx)  for rule configuration. And use sheduled service which is supposed to fill event instances table  for today(or longer period) based on rule config table. But this solution brings complexity of maintenance of event instances table if rule config will be changed. Maybe there is a built in calendar functionality in android?
- **Which is the best way to manage user notifications?** I heard about AlarmManager class but is it flexible enough to handle rule reconfiguration or cancellation of event?